# Virtualenv not recognised in ipython Notebook Server

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have iPython running from a [secured server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/notebook/public_server.html#notebook-server-security) on an Ubuntu server VM running on my laptop.

Command line ipython works on the server vm from the virtualenv. I can also start the notebook server on the server vm from the virtualenv without errors.

I can access notebooks from the host laptop and execute code in cells, but if I start the notebook server after activating a virtualenv I can't import any of the Python modules I've installed in the virtualenv.

It looks like the notebook server process is running the system Python but not the version in my virtualenv. Is there a way to tell the notebook server process which virtualenv to use?

Answer (score 0):

Because virtualenv on activation adds its own ways to the begining of the `PATH` environment variable, you have two options:

a) create correct virtualenv on the notebook server and install everything from there

b) modify `PYTHONPATH` variable in order to get access to your libraries.

Comment: I understand that and use virtualenvs on both host and virtual machine. But this doesn't explain the problem. If I activate the virtualenv on the server and start iPython it works with the virtualenv. If I activate the virtualenv on the server and start iPython notebook it does not use the virtualenv.

Comment: Check variables ``PATH``, ``PYTHONPATH``, ``VIRTUAL_ENV``, if they are identical, the only case is it is somehow coded inside the iPython's notebook.